# How can I generate multiple function pointers from a parameterized base function?

Tags: c++

I have a base function

`int base(const int i, const double &x)`

In this function, I consider `i` to be a "parameter" (which can take predefined values from 0 to N-1), while `x` I consider to be the actual "argument" (which can take any arbitrary value).

What I need is to create an array of function pointers `int (*pointers[N])(const double &x)`.  Each member of the array corresponds to a different value for the parameter `i` and thus each call `pointers[n](x)` should be equivalent to a call `base(n, x)`.

Is there a way to achieve this functionality?

I have been trying to educate myself about functors (is this a way to go?) and recently also looked into `std::bind` but my understanding is that it only works with C++11 (which I currently cannot use).

Any advice or code snippet would be really helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use non-capturing lambdas for that:

```
typedef int (*fp)(double);

fp p1 = [](double x) -> int { return base(1, x); };
fp p2 = [](double x) -> int { return base(2, x); };
fp p3 = [](double x) -> int { return base(3, x); };
```

This doesn't work for capturing lambdas, and so you can't generate those programatically. There's essentially no difference between this and spelling out one function for each value in C:

```
int f1(double x) { return base(1, x); }
fp p = f1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!....the problem is the following: The number of different parameter values is large and, more importantly, not known at compile-time.  Thus, I cannot just casually write "p1", "p2", "p3", "f1", etc....I need to be able to do commands in a loop over i....

Comment: @Chrys: Unfortunately, functions in C++ are not real first-class objects, and you cannot create functions dynamically. If you could use function-like objects, it would be trivial, but not with raw function pointers. They just don't carry enough state.

Comment: I need to use raw pointers in order to interface with legacy code originally written in Fortran, which I have been calling through C (which has been a mess of its own)....I have been thinking along the lines of using a functor class, the call operator of which will be linked to each different function, and a different object of which functor will be created in the loop over the parameter values (however, I am not too proficient to know how to do this exactly)

Comment: @Chrys: You can't do that. A raw C function has no state, and you cannot make something that has more state than none at all look like a raw C function...